# Подскажите как сделать вот такой блок?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как создать такой блок? transform: perspective(..) rotateY(..) дает не тот угол наклона.

Comment: tilt.js - посморите

Comment: https://gijsroge.github.io/tilt.js/

Comment: Почему не тот угол? Через CSS это так и так делается...

Comment: получается что здесь перспектива идет слева на право и снизу вверх,  а css делает сверху вниз.

Comment: @НиколайМуравьев у вас там нет перспективы, обычный наклон + градиент = обман зрения. См пример ниже.

Answer (score 8):

```css
html, 
body {
  background: #00004d;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rectangle {
  transform: skew(0, -18deg);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.rectangle__body {
  background: #103d10;
  width: 180px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.rectangle__body:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #29a329,  #71da71);
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.rectangle__shadow {
  filter: blur(7px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 120px;
}

.rectangle__label {
  color: #ebfaeb;
  position: absolute; 
  width: 130px;
  left: 90px;
  top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="rectangle__body"></div>
  <div class="rectangle__body">
    <div class="rectangle__shadow">тень на две строки</div>
  </div>
  <div class="rectangle__label">
    Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

```js
const rectangleNode = document.querySelector('.rectangle');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  move(e.x, e.y, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

function move(eventX, eventY, windowWidth, windowHeight) {
  const x = (eventX / windowWidth) * 2 - 1;
  const y = (eventY / windowHeight) * 2 - 1;
  rectangleNode.style.setProperty('--x', x);
  rectangleNode.style.setProperty('--y', y);
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --transitionTimingFunction: ease;
  --transitionDuration: 0.05s;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 26, 52);
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rectangle {
  --x: 1;
  --y: 1;
  --maxTranslateX: 20px;
  --maxTranslateY: 20px;
  --background: linear-gradient(to right top, #29a329, #71da71);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  --skewDeg: calc(-18deg * var(--x) * var(--y));
  transform: skew(0, var(--skewDeg));
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.rectangle__body {
  padding: 35px 25px;
  background: var(--background);
  max-width: 180px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rectangle__body-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  --maxTranslateX: 50px;
  --maxTranslateY: 50px;
  --translateX: calc( (var(--maxTranslateX) * var(--x) + 0px) * -1);
  --translateY: calc( (var(--maxTranslateY) * var(--y) + 0px) * -1);
  transform: translate3d( var(--translateX), var(--translateY), 0);
}

.rectangle__body-pos-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.rectangle__body-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rectangle__body-text-span {
  display: block;
  --translateX: calc( var(--maxTranslateX) * var(--x));
  --translateY: calc( var(--maxTranslateY) * var(--y));
  transform: translate3d( var(--translateX), var(--translateY), 0);
}

.rectangle__body-text-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(7px);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">

  <div class="rectangle__body-shadow">
  </div>

  <div class="rectangle__body">
    <div class="rectangle__body-pos-relative">

      <div class="rectangle__body-text">
        <span class="rectangle__body-text-span">Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений</span>
      </div>

      <div class="rectangle__body-text-shadow">
        Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

UPD: доработанная версия c плавностью, производительностью(requestAnimationFrame), ресайзом и поддержкой тача

```js
const htmlNode = document.documentElement;
const defaultMouseX = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(htmlNode).getPropertyValue('--mouse-x'));
const defaultMouseY = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(htmlNode).getPropertyValue('--mouse-y'));

let currentX = 0;
let currentY = 0;
let lastCurrentX = 0;
let lastCurrentY = 0;
let targetX = 0;
let targetY = 0;
let targetXPercent = 0;
let targetYPercent = 0;
let animated = false;
const ease = 0.05; // значение, определяющее скорость анимации или изменения координат

window.addEventListener('pointermove', onMove);
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);

function onResize(e) {
  targetX = targetXPercent * window.innerWidth;
  targetY = targetYPercent * window.innerHeight;
}

function onMove(e) {
  targetX = e.clientX;
  targetY = e.clientY;

  // это сделано, чтобы не выходить за пределы экрана браузера
  targetX = Math.min(Math.max(targetX, 0), window.innerWidth);
  targetY = Math.min(Math.max(targetY, 0), window.innerHeight);
  // это сделано, чтобы не выходить за пределы экрана браузера

  targetXPercent = targetX / window.innerWidth;
  targetYPercent = targetY / window.innerHeight;

  animated = true;
}

function animate() {
  if (animated === false) {
    targetX = defaultMouseX * window.innerWidth;
    targetY = defaultMouseY * window.innerHeight;
    targetXPercent = targetX / window.innerWidth;
    targetYPercent = targetY / window.innerHeight;
    currentX = targetX;
    currentY = targetY;
    animated = true;
  }

  currentX = currentX + ((targetX - currentX) * ease);
  currentY = currentY + ((targetY - currentY) * ease);

  // преобразуем координаты в диапазон от 0 до 1
  let x = currentX / window.innerWidth;
  let y = currentY / window.innerHeight;

  // округляем до 3 чисел после запятой
  x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(3));
  y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(3));

  // устанавливаем соответствующие CSS-переменные
  if (x !== lastCurrentX) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', x);
    lastCurrentX = x;
  }

  if (y !== lastCurrentY) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', y);
    lastCurrentY = y;
  }


  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  /* от 0 до 1 эти CSS переменные */
  --mouse-x: 0.2;
  --mouse-y: 0.7;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(0, 26, 52);
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  touch-action: none;
}

.rectangle {
  --borderRadius: 20px;
  --background: linear-gradient(to right top, #29a329, #71da71);
  /* от -1 до 1 эти CSS переменные */
  --x: calc(var(--mouse-x) * 2 - 1);
  --y: calc(var(--mouse-y) * 2 - 1);
  /* от -1 до 1 эти CSS переменные */
  --skewDeg: calc(-18deg * var(--x) * var(--y));
  --maxTranslateX: 20px;
  --maxTranslateY: 20px;
  transform: skew(0, var(--skewDeg));
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.3;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.rectangle__body-shadow {
  --maxTranslateXShadow: calc(var(--maxTranslateX) * 2.5);
  --maxTranslateYShadow: calc(var(--maxTranslateY) * 2.5);
  --translateX: calc( var(--maxTranslateXShadow) * var(--x) * -1);
  --translateY: calc( var(--maxTranslateYShadow) * var(--y) * -1);
  transform: translate3d( var(--translateX), var(--translateY), 0);
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
  background: var(--background);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rectangle__body {
  padding: 35px 25px;
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rectangle__body-pos-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.rectangle__body-text-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  filter: blur(7px);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.rectangle__body-text {
  --translateX: calc( var(--maxTranslateX) * var(--x));
  --translateY: calc( var(--maxTranslateY) * var(--y));
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate3d( var(--translateX), var(--translateY), 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="rectangle__body-shadow"></div>
  <div class="rectangle__body">
    <div class="rectangle__body-pos-relative">
      <div class="rectangle__body-text-shadow">
        Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений
      </div>
      <div class="rectangle__body-text">
        Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. Круто

Comment: @Alexandr_TT благодарю :)