# Здравствуйте. Кто может сказать, как реализовать такую же подсветку карточек, как на сайте ниже?

Tags: javascript

Вот есть пример, сделанный на тильде, возможно ли сделать такой же эффект подсветки только при помощи чистого js, html, css
http://matilda-template.tilda.ws/cards-light

Comment: Открою страшный секрет. Тильда тоже сделана на чистом HTML, JS и CSS. И конкретно на той странице простой JS который просто двигает радиальный градиент в фоне блока. https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Tdz.png

Comment: На чем бы ни был сайт сделан, в браузере работает только html, js, css. По ссылке выше, с мобилы, никакого эффекта не увидел и сайт не адаптирован...

Comment: https://codepen.io/bramus/pen/eBZgPB вот например простейший скрипт который можно немного допилить

Comment: Alexey Ten, спасибо огромное за помощь!!!

Comment: @Кирилл также могу посоветовать свою обучалку с 3D карточкой, технологии похожие - https://youtu.be/j0i9rG-YFz4?si=isHFgDZqV1a2iLe2 или вот просто код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1319792/331312